# Typing the initial state of a custom useForm hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I use a custom hook for my form inputs, but I have some trouble to implement typescript here.

```
const useForm = (initial) => {
  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState(initial);
  
  // rest of the hook

 return { inputs, onChange, clearInputs };
}
```

I use it as follows:

```
const { inputs, handleChange, resetForm } = useForm({ name: "", age: 25, city: "Amsterdam" });
```

**The issue:**
`inputs` has type `Any`, i want it to have type `{ name: string, age: number, city: string }`

I want the hook to be generic, so for example in another file I use different fields like
`useForm({distance: 40, hours: 2, speed: 5 })` where I expect the types to be `{ distance: number, hours: number, speed: number }`

**expectation:**
I hope to give some types along with the `useForm()` function where i define the initial state.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a generic function with a type parameter `T` that extends `Map<string, string|number>`, and use that to type `initial`. From there, the type `inputs` should be inferred for you.

```
const useForm = <T extends Map<string, string|number>>(initial: T) => {
  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState(initial);
  
  // rest of the hook

  return { inputs, onChange, clearInputs };
}
```